# Problems by reading csv file into R

Tags: r, csv

Just starting with R and trying to read a huge csv file into R.

The Raw data contains 3452 observations an 1331 variables. (Im working with the 64 bit version of R on Windwos 10.)

[image: Row data file looks like this:]

I tried:

1. mydata <- read.csv(file="piaac.csv", header = TRUE,na.strings="?", sep=",")
2. mydata <- read.csv(file="piaac.csv", header = TRUE,na.strings="?", sep=",", dec = ".")

but after reading the file into R all values are apearing under one variable (column) while the other columns (1331) only contain "NA" values over all 3452 rows.[Data file in R](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2Ttk.png)

Does anyone know how to fix this?

thx

Comment: what data type is mydata? A dataframe? And you might want to include stringsAsFactors=FALSE and make sure the CSV is encoded correctly (not all csv are created equally).

Comment: Please post the content of the csv in your post and not as an image. Open csv in text editor then copy/paste with code format (CTRL/CMD + K).

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that your image is from a spreadsheet, in which case that "column" with commas will be saved with quote-delimiting to keep commas within the one cell. One way to test this:

```r
writeLines(c('"a,b"','"1,2"','"3,4"'), "foo.csv")
dat <- readLines("foo.csv")
dat[1:2]
# [1] "\"a,b\"" "\"1,2\""

read.csv("foo.csv") ### obviously a problem
#   a.b
# 1 1,2
# 2 3,4
```

(Note the extra leading/trailing double quotes.)

I think ultimately this should be fixed at the source, since it is arguably a problem of whatever created (or edited incorrectly) that file. Until then, here's a possible R fix:

```r
read.csv(text = gsub('(^"|"$)', '', readLines("foo.csv")))
#   a b
# 1 1 2
# 2 3 4
```

Comment: @NirbhaySingh, it usually makes more sense to make an answer-edit suggestion like that in a comment.